# Why doesn't the standard allow usage of importScripts() outside of a web worker?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

What's the technical/security/... reason for not providing the importScripts() in the main thread as well?

I know it's easy to implement in alternative ways (adding script tags, XHR+eval), that's not the question. I just wonder if there's a good reason for this limitation.

Comment: There's no reason. As you said there already are lots of ways to load scripts, and the `importScripts` interface was only specified because none of those ways works in a WebWorker environment.

Comment: @Bergi -- won't jQuery's getScript() work in a web worker? Or, for that matter, XHR+eval?

Comment: Afaik `getScript` adds `<script>` elements to the DOM, which is obviously not possible in a WebWorker. A (even synchronous) XHR + `eval` would be possible, since that is also explicitly available, but it would be cumbersome imho. So they introduced `importScripts` on the `WorkerUtils` interface, not in the DOM `Window` where it would make less sense and needed to be specified differently.

Comment: @Bergi: this brings back my original question: why not introduce that convenient utility on Window as well? I guess there's no good reason.

Comment: Same question in me. How should i write my scripts with fallback to no worker support?! It requires too much effort because of the synchronous nature of importScripts